# How can I print a list?

Tags: python, list

I have this json file:

```
    [
      {"industry": "food", "price": 100.0, "name": "mcdonald's"}, 
      {"industry": "food", "price": 90.0, "name": "tacobell"}, 
      {"industry": "food", "price": 150.0, "name": "Subway"}, 
      {"industry": "Cars", "price": 90.0, "name": "Audi"}
    ]
```

This is my code:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('firm_list.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())
pprint(data)
    
result_list=[]
for json_dict in data:
    result_list.append(json_dict['price'])
result_list=[json_dict['price'] for json_dict in data]
result_list.sort(reverse= True)
print(result_list)
```

I want to print a list of firms in the food industry and respective prices, which is
sorted by the price, with the highest price appearing first. But my code print in the list also the firm from the car industry. How can I print just the firms from the food industry? Is it possible to have the name of the firms on the list too?

Comment: `data.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda i: i['price']); print(data)`…

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and, in the future, try to communicate your problems with the code more clearly. I was confused here because you have titled the question "how can I print a list?", but clearly you already have code that successfully prints lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter by food industry then sort the result:

```
import json

with open('example.json') as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())

data = [i for i in data if i['industry'] == 'food']
data.sort(key=lambda i: i['price'], reverse=True)
# EDIT: filtering keys in dictionaries
data = [{k: d[k] for k in ['name', 'price']} for d in data]
print(data)
```

Result:

```
[{'price': 90.0, 'name': 'tacobell'}, {'price': 100.0, 'name': "mcdonald's"}, {'price': 150.0, 'name': 'Subway'}]
```

Comment: And how can I have the result printed from the highest price to the lowest?

Comment: use `data.sort(key=lambda i: i['price'], reverse=True)`, see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: Thank you. And what about if I want to print just the price and the name, but not the industry? Do you have any documents to recommend?

Comment: At this point `data` just holds JSON, you can read up about the structure of JSON online. In python, your JSON is serialized into a list of dictionaries see [python JSON docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). That way you can loop through each of the dictionaries and pull out the price and the name.

Comment: `data = [{k: d[k] for k in ['name', 'price']} for d in data]` should do it.

Comment: Can you put this into your code? Because if I write data = [{k: d[k] for k in ['name', 'price']} for d in data], I have an error when I put the if statement to have ['industry']=='food'

Comment: @Moly see the edit in the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `if` filter to your list comprehension:

```
result_list = [
    json_dict['price']
    for json_dict in data
    if json_dict['industry'] == 'food'
]
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I can add the name of the firms to the list?

Comment: What one of the other answers wrote... https://stackoverflow.com/a/69925352/683329

Comment: Yes, but that code doesn't print the result from the highest to the lowest as I would like.

Comment: Right, they've updated their answer to do that now. In general, it's like Lego - solve the problems by putting together small pieces, rather than in one big chunk...

Answer (score 0):

In the line 9 of the code, you are appending all the price to result_list. You might want to add a check. append that price to the results only if `json_dict['industry'] == 'food'`

```py
result_list=[]

for json_dict in data:
    if (json_dict['price']):
        result_list.append(json_dict['price'])

result_list.sort(reverse= True)
print(result_list)
```

Also, `result_list=[json_dict['price'] for json_dict in data]` seems like a redundant line to me. I don't think it's required there.